# How to prevent a set of MSIs with common Upgrade code from installing post install of my msi?

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

I distribute 2 msis A.msi and B.msi . I have been distributing it for long time and every new release maintains the same Upgrade code and new higher version.

I have now a new msi C.msi . After installing C.msi, I want that the users should not be allowed to install any version of A.msi and B.msi . C.msi removes any existing A.msi and B.msi but I am unable to prevent installation post C.msi install.

I use WIX to build my MSI.

Comment: Do all packages (A, B and C) use the same UpgradeCode? If they do, all you need to do is make sure that C has a higher version than all previous releases. Windows Installer doesn't support downgrades by default.

Comment: nope each have different code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent already distributed installers from being installed over another package. So there's not much you can do.

It would have worked only if A and B would have been configured from the start to stop if C is found.